# When I insert a newly registered user in the DB, should my AddUser() extend AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Do I need to turn this method into a class and extend AsyncTask in order to use it?
Somewhere I read I should never run DB operations from the UI Thread?

And if so, how do I go about doing that?

Here is the code ATM:

```
public void addNewContact() {
    HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    queryValuesMap.put("userName", userName);
    queryValuesMap.put("userEmail", userEmail);
    queryValuesMap.put("userPassword", userPassword);
    queryValuesMap.put("userAvatar", userAvatar);
    queryValuesMap.put("userSex", userSex);
    dbTools.insertUser(queryValuesMap);
    dbTools.close();
}
```

and it gets called from my submit button onClick().

What I suppose I should do is the following:

```
private class AddNewContact extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
            HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                queryValuesMap.put("userName", userName);
                queryValuesMap.put("userEmail", userEmail);
                queryValuesMap.put("userPassword", userPassword);
                queryValuesMap.put("userAvatar", userAvatar);
                queryValuesMap.put("userSex", userSex);
                dbTools.insertUser(queryValuesMap);
                dbTools.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then AddNewContact.execute() in the submit button onClick().

Is this right?

**EDIT: Here is the working code after implementing what was in the discussion below the accepted answer:**

in the onClick:

```
        AddNewUserParams addNewUserParams = new AddNewUserParams();
        addNewUserParams.userName = this.userName;
        addNewUserParams.userEmail = this.userEmail;
        addNewUserParams.userPassword = this.userPassword;
        addNewUserParams.userAvatar = this.userAvatar;
        addNewUserParams.userSex = this.userSex;

        new AddNewContact().execute(addNewUserParams);
```

and here are the nested classes:

```
private class AddNewUserParams {
    String userName;
    String userEmail;
    String userPassword;
    String userAvatar;
    String userSex;
}
private class AddNewContact extends AsyncTask <AddNewUserParams, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(AddNewUserParams... params) {
        try {
        HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            queryValuesMap.put("userName", params[0].userName);
            queryValuesMap.put("userEmail", params[0].userEmail);
            queryValuesMap.put("userPassword", params[0].userPassword);
            queryValuesMap.put("userAvatar", params[0].userAvatar);
            queryValuesMap.put("userSex", params[0].userSex);
            dbTools.insertUser(queryValuesMap);
            dbTools.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            toastMaker.toast(net.asdqwe.activities.Signup.this, configurationz.ERROR_MESSAGES_SIGNUP_USER_NOT_CREATED, configurationz, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Intent signupSuccessHome = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
        signupSuccessHome.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, userEmail);
        startActivity(signupSuccessHome);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly is, yes.

All View callbacks (onClick, etc) execute on the main thread. You should make sure that nothing that touches disk or network executes on the main thread too. In particular, DB access, networking, file reading/writing, and long-running calculations should all go on different threads (by, for example, using `AsyncTask`).

You're doing two wrong things, though.

1) You're not passing in the parameters of the operation (username, password, etc). You can set the `Params` template argument (the first one) to `String` and that will give you a signature of `Void doInBackground(String.. params)`. That way, the idea of the operation is separated from the particular values you might be inserting at the moment.

2) You're suppressing failure. That try-empty-catch-all block is a really, really bad practice and you should avoid it. You can change the Result type to Boolean and then handle both results in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: can you show me how to implement that in my code? Im not sure about the Params thing.

Comment: @J.Kowalski see my answer below

Comment: Well, your class will become `class AddNewContact extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Void>` and then you would call it with `execute(userName, userEmail, userPassword, ..)`. Inside `doInBackground`, you will have access to these parameters with `params[0]`, `params[1]`, etc. Since you have so many of them, I would put them in a class of their own, say `AddUserParams` and then use that in place of `String`. That way, reading the values would be `params[0].userName`, `params[0].userEmail`, which is far more readable.

Comment: and what do I do with this line:
is it okay this way?
new AddNewContact().execute(new AddNewUserParams());

Comment: Well, you would have to make the `AddNewUserParams` object before the `execute` call, so that you can fill all the fields inside it. Then, you can call execute with the filled object.

Comment: I have some problem, the next activity isnt receiving anything, I've updated my question with an EDIT, could you take a look at it?

Comment: Two points - I definitely didn't mean to have `String userName = Signup.this.userName;` but rather `addNewUserParams.userName = this.userName` in `onClick`. That way, `AddNewUser` and `AddNewUserParams` can be static and entirely independent of the `Activity`. Second, it's most likely a race condition - you're not waiting for the write to finish before you start the next activity. Try moving your `startActivity` call to `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 1):

**You should never run DB operations from the UI Thread** is **correct** unless you are doing long operations in UI thread. The main reason for doing so is not to slow down the UI thread. As you are inserting a very small values in DB you can use your code without any worry but make this a habit of using Async Task to insert/retrieve data into database so as not to slow down the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

**AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.**   [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

In simple things like networking task, db handling should be handled in a seperate thread rather than the main UI thread.

As for your question: yes use an Aysnc task

What you have written above is nearly correct:

The first parameter needs to be String to pass in a array of strings accessible in `protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {` by `strings[0] = userName etc...` or create the HashMap before and pass in the hashmap as the first parameter. It is also bad practise to have empty catch blocks and you should atleast log an error.

**ADDED CODE**

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
        HashMap<String, String> queryValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            queryValuesMap.put("userName", params[0]);
            queryValuesMap.put("userEmail", params[1]);
            queryValuesMap.put("userPassword", params[2]);
            queryValuesMap.put("userAvatar", params[3]);
            queryValuesMap.put("userSex", params[4]);
            dbTools.insertUser(queryValuesMap);
            dbTools.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
```

You would call your new `Async Class` like so:

```
new AddNewContact().execute(userName, email, etc...);
```

If you want to show a `progress dialog` to the user you can override onPreExecute and onPostExecute like so:

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
           progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```